# Media queries and screen orientation

Tags: css, media-queries, landscape-portrait

I'm creating a responsive design web page, and I want to ensure I do all the media queries correctly for different devices and orientations.

This post suggests try using min-width and min-height media queries. And set up different break points for different resolutions.

[screen orientation for multiple tablets with fluid design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8581998/screen-orientation-for-multiple-tablets-with-fluid-design)

Although, I found this method with the orientation (see below).
Should I use this approach or the one above?
Should I use @media screen, or should I consider all vs screen?

```
    @media screen and (min-width: 700px) and (orientation: landscape) { ... }
```

Comment: FWIW, I haven't had major issues by defaulting to `@media () {}` and only applying `screen`, `print`, etc when needed. Using `orientation: landscape` is going to depend on **your** site's requirements. I would only use `orientation` as a refinement to an existing media query. I can count the number of times I've had to use `orientation` by the number of times I've won the lottery. Note, what you have above will not apply any styles when a device is `701px` or greater and in `portrait`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Screen orientation is an interesting one as it's not always something that's reported back by the device/browser, so it's less reliable to use than min-width/max-width.

The other thing is that unless you're trying to do a particularly funky thing when the device is in landscape, then just adjusting your design based on width breakpoints is usually enough to get your desired effect.

If you have a landscape device, then it's probably okay to let the design display as it would at portrait with the same horizontal space. That is to say, it wouldn't be an unexpected behaviour for the user.

As for media `all` vs `screen`, I usually just stick with screen, as should the user want to do something like print the page, I don't necessarily want my break points to interfere in that.

As with anything though, you should think about the most common use cases for your users and make your decisions based on that. If it's just a regular web app/page, then there is nothing wrong at all with using just `screen` and not worrying about `orientation`.

Comment: Also, I have read it is best to design from smallest to largest screen. Would this be the best process to follow? Thank for the response.

Comment: Unless you think nearly all your traffic will be on desktop, then starting with a small screen design is a great idea. The reason for this is it makes you think quite critically about the important components of your design, because you may have to make sacrifices at smaller screen sizes. So as well as helping with design, it also makes you consider elements of the product/platform itself - which is a great exercise.

Comment: Our main user is on a desktop or laptop, but we want to be ready to support other devices down the road. Although that could be quite sometime before that happens. Thank you for the help.